# Why does animation auto stop while onPause

Tags: android, animation, lifecycle

```
view.startAnimation(myAnimation)
```

I set an animation to some view, everything works.

but if the view go to `onPause` lifecycle (activity、fragment、customView etc..) and go back to `onResume`

the animation will stop.

Is there any idea to make view animation **dont** auto stop?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
private long animationPausedTime;

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Pause the animation and record the paused time
    animationPausedTime = myAnimation.getStartTime() + myAnimation.getDuration() - System.currentTimeMillis();
    view.clearAnimation();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Resume the animation with remaining time
    myAnimation.setStartTime(System.currentTimeMillis() - myAnimation.getDuration() + animationPausedTime);
    view.startAnimation(myAnimation);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, is there any method or property in animation? I don't want to write `onResume` and 'onPause` everywhere.

Comment: No, there is not any `attribute` available to prevent the animation auto stop. You need to manage it dynamically as I said. 
Without using `onResume` & `onPause` you can't manage animation.
I check this entire reference but didn't find anything.
[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation]